# Stylesheet is not working with dynamic buttons in qml

Tags: qt, qml

In my project I managed to populate some buttons in a grid layout using component. But I cannot add style component to the button. This is my code:

```
Component {
    id: itemgroup
    Button { }
}

function addButton () {
    for(var i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) {
    var button = itemgroup.createObject (gridX, {
                                            "id": "btnitemgroup",
                                            "style": buttonstyle,
                                            "text"   :"hai"
                                        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What are your requirements? Do you need to change the `buttonstyle` with every function call, or is there another reason why you don't set up the style where you set up the component? What is the reason for using a JS function instead of doing it the declarative way, using a `Repeater`?

Comment: @derM no specific reason for using JS function.Is there any major difference between them

Comment: JS created objects are garbage collected. The GC tends to be buggy, so blessed are those that can avoid them. Further it is a matter of style: QML is a declarative language, so good style is staying declarative. Additionally, complex JS expressions are the slowest part in the language stack of C++/QML/JS, as they are not optimized and are parsed at run time.

Answer (score 0):

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.3

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 500
    height: 500
    id:root
    Grid
    {
        id:gridX
    }
    function addButton (row) {

        var styleButton = 'import QtQuick 2.6;import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
            import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.3; Button { text:"hai";  style: ButtonStyle {
             background: Rectangle {
              implicitWidth: 100
              implicitHeight: 25
              border.width: control.activeFocus ? 2 : 1
              border.color: "red"
              radius: 10
                 }
                }
            }'

       for(var i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) {
            Qt.createQmlObject(styleButton, gridX);
        }
    }
    Component.onCompleted:
    {
        addButton()
    }
}
```

[image]